# $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a perfect set

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Given the standard Euclidian metric I want to show that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a perfect set, that is to say, it contains all of its limit points and every point is a limit point.

This question comes from a table presented in Rudin's principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Attempt:

Consider the complement of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ i.e. $(\mathbb{R}^{2})^{c} = \emptyset$. Then it follows $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is closed since the emptyset is open. Thus $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ contains all its limit points.

Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ then for all $\epsilon > 0$, let $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ denote the ball of radius epsilon centred at $x$. Then $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{x\} \neq \emptyset$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, every point is a limit point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. I would just add a justification of the assertion that $(B_\varepsilon(x)\cap\Bbb R^2)\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset$. You can say, for instance, that$$x+\left(\frac\varepsilon2,0\right)\in(B_\varepsilon(x)\cap\Bbb R^2)\setminus\{x\}.$$

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.